# I have wrong answer for project Euler#8

Tags: java, string

I can't know why wrong this question. I search google although I can't understand. Thank you for helping :).The problem is=

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String str= "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"+
                "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"+
                "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"+
                "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"+
                "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"+
                "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"+
                "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"+
                "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"+
                "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"+
                "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"+
                "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"+
                "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"+
                "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"+
                "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"+
                "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"+
                "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"+
                "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"+
                "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"+
                "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"+
                "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    char chr[] = new char[str.length()];
    chr=str.toCharArray();
    long bignumber=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chr.length; i++) 
    {
        if(i<=986)
        {
            if(chr[i+0]*chr[i+1]*chr[i+2]*chr[i+3]*chr[i+4]*chr[i+5]*chr[i+6]*chr[i+7]*chr[i+8]*chr[i+9]*chr[i+10]*chr[i+11]*chr[i+12]>bignumber)
            {
                bignumber=chr[i+0]*chr[i+1]*chr[i+2]*chr[i+3]*chr[i+4]*chr[i+5]*chr[i+6]*chr[i+7]*chr[i+8]*chr[i+9]*chr[i+10]*chr[i+11]*chr[i+12];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(bignumber);
}
```

Comment: You are comparing by character value here, not by their digit value. Easiest is just to subtract `'0'` from each `chr[i+n]`, especially if you refactor that into a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product is ***23514624000***.
Sequence is ***5576689664895***.

code is -

```
public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String str= "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"+
                "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"+
                "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"+
                "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"+
                "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"+
                "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"+
                "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"+
                "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"+
                "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"+
                "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"+
                "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"+
                "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"+
                "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"+
                "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"+
                "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"+
                "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"+
                "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"+
                "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"+
                "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"+
                "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    char chr[] = new char[str.length()];
    chr=str.toCharArray();
    long product = 0;
    String digits = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chr.length - 13; i++) 
    {   
        long product1 = (long)Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+0])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+1])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+2])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+3])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+4])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+5])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+6])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+7])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+8])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+9])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+10])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+11])*Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+12]);

        if(product < product1)
            {
                product = product1;
                digits = ""+chr[i+0]+chr[i+1]+chr[i+2]+chr[i+3]+chr[i+4]+chr[i+5]+chr[i+6]+chr[i+7]+chr[i+8]+chr[i+9]+chr[i+10]+chr[i+11]+chr[i+12];
            }
    }
    System.out.println(product);
    System.out.println(digits);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are multiplying the numeric values of the characters instead of multiplying the digits.

Replace `chr[i+x]` with `Character.getNumericValue(chr[i+x])`.

Beside that, performing the multiplication twice for each 13 digits is wasteful. Do the multiplication once and store the result in a variable, so that you can re-use it.

Better yet, in each iteration you can take the result of the previous iteration, divide by the first digit of the previous iteration and multiply by the last digit of the current iteration. This will save you many multiplications. EDIT : Actually this optimization can only work if there are no zeroes in the number, so you can forget about it.